# How can I get an error report when I execute a command in Ubuntu server? (Backup on PostgreSQL)

Tags: command-line, server, postgresql

I have to do a backup of a (heavy) PostgreSQL database in Ubuntu Server and I want to make sure that I don't have any fails.  The command is:

```
pg_dump database_name -h localhost -p port_number >> backup_file.sql
```

What do I have to add to this command to get an error report (if there is any error) in a specific location?

Comment: Thanks @dessert,I think the problem was that i wasn't searching for the correct words for my problem. All the questions i found didn't answer mine. Thanks again.

Comment: That’s exactly what the duplicate marking feature is for: Now your question serves as a signpost for others choosing your wording and redirects them to possible solutions. Thanks for asking!

Comment: I didn't want to do anything with the cp command. It was only in case it helped to understand the question to someone who wasn't familiar with PostgresQL, since pg_dump (with its nuances of course) has similarities with cp. Sorry if the question causes some confusion.